# How do I verify that a solution returned by Solve is correct?

Tags: equation-solving

I used `Solve` to solve the equation $3\, x^3 + 4.3\, x^2 + 10.1\, x = 12.3$

```
sol = Solve[3 x^3 + 4.3 x^2 + 10.1 x == 12.3, x]
```

> `{{x -> -1.11517 - 1.97501 I}, {x -> -1.11517 + 1.97501 I}, {x -> 0.797005}}`

I tried to verify the solution with

```
3 x^3 + 4.3 x^2 + 10.1 x /. sol
```

and got

```
{12.3 + 1.15463*10^-14 I, 12.3- 1.15463*10^-14 I, 12.3}
```

I expected

```
{12.3, 12.3, 12.3}
```

What did I do wrong? How can I properly back substitute the results into the equation?

Comment: Please do not post images of your work; rather, post your actual Mathematica code in the form of text that can be copied and pasted into a Mathematica notebook. Without such, it will be difficult to reproduce your problem and to experiment with possible solutions.

Comment: It is not clear what the question is here. Please edit the post and make the question explicit.

Answer (score 3):

```
sol = Solve[3 x^3 + 4.3 x^2 + 10.1 x == 12.3, x]
```

> `{{x -> -1.11517 - 1.97501 I}, {x -> -1.11517 + 1.97501 I}, {x -> 0.797005}}`

Verification

```
Chop[3 x^3 + 4.3 x^2 + 10.1 x /. sol]
```

> `{12.3, 12.3, 12.3}`

Note: The function [`Chop`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Chop.html) must be applied because your equation has coefficients given as machine floating point numbers. These inexact coefficients cause extraneous tiny imaginary parts to appear in result of the back substitution of `sol`. `Chop` removes these imaginary parts.

#### Update

If you were to use exact coefficients, you would get a more complex result (pun not intended) but `Chop` would not be necessary.

```
sol = Solve[3 x^3 + 43/10 x^2 + 101/10 x == 123/10, x]
Simplify[3 x^3 + 43/10 x^2 + 101/10 x /. sol]
```

> `{123/10, 123/10, 123/10}`

Comment: MarcoB. Thanks for edit.

Answer (score 3):

```
eqn = 3 x^3 + 4.3 x^2 + 10.1 x == 12.3;
```

Using exact numbers

```
sol1 = Solve[eqn // Rationalize, x] // Simplify

(*  {{x -> (1/90)*(-43 - 
            7241/(2001248 + 
                   45*Sqrt[2165261361])^
                (1/3) + (2001248 + 
                 45*Sqrt[2165261361])^
              (1/3))}, 
   {x -> (1/180)*(-86 + 
            (7241*(1 + I*Sqrt[3]))/
              (2001248 + 45*Sqrt[
                       2165261361])^(1/3) + 
            I*(I + Sqrt[3])*
              (2001248 + 45*Sqrt[
                       2165261361])^(1/3))}, 
   {x -> (1/180)*(-86 + 
            (7241*(1 - I*Sqrt[3]))/
              (2001248 + 45*Sqrt[
                       2165261361])^(1/3) + 
            (-1 - I*Sqrt[3])*
              (2001248 + 45*Sqrt[
                       2165261361])^(1/3))}}  *)

(eqn // Rationalize) /. sol1 // Simplify

(*  {True, True, True}  *)
```

Using high precision

```
sol2 = Solve[SetPrecision[eqn, 20], x, WorkingPrecision -> 20]

(*  {{x -> -1.115169237798952334 - 
    1.975007714358509930 I}, {x -> -1.115169237798952334 + 
    1.975007714358509930 I}, {x -> 0.7970051422645713930}}  *)

SetPrecision[eqn, 20] /. sol2

(*  {True, True, True}  *)
```

Answer (score -2):

Sorry for a so stupid comment ->(As there is only one real solution). I apologize :

```
sol = Solve[3 x^3 + 4.3 x^2 + 10.1 x == 12 , x]
Chop[3 x^3 + 4.3 x^2 + 10.1 x /. {sol[[1]],sol[[2]],sol[[3]]}
```

only to show that sol could be also call element by element